# Getting NULL data from collection from MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have connected my code to [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/) using [Mongoose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongoose_(web_server))... even though the collection has a data in it its shows null in response.

---

I want to know the exact issue and troubleshoot it, because the collection has the data required

Collection details are in this image:

[image]

```
1. Connectivity Code -
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-3awwl.mongodb.net/";
mongoose.connect(uri, {
    dbName: 'bing_bot'
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log('Database connectivity error ', e)
})

2.Model-
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Student = mongoose.model('student', {
    StudentName: {
        type:String
    },
    Contact: {
        type:String
    },
    Email: {
        type:String
    },
    BNo: {
        type:String
    },
    Year: {
        type:String
    }
})
 module.exports = Student`enter code here`

3. Retrieve data -
Student.findById(_id).then((data) => {
        console.log('data: ', data)})


4. Using MongoCLient

const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-3awwl.mongodb.net/bing_bot"
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
   if(err) {
        console.log('Error occurred while connecting to MongoDB Atlas...\n', err);
   }
   console.log('Connected...');
   const collection = client.db("bing_bot").collection("student");
   // perform actions on the collection object
   collection.findOne({
       "StudentName": "Test"
   }).then((d) => {
       console.log('data: ', d)
   })

   const data = collection.find()
   console.log('data:1 ', data)
   client.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `mongoose` instances in your `Connectivity Code` and `Model` are different and unrelated. One is connected (Connectivity), but the other (Model) is not. You've to use the same instance so export one `mongoose` and import that where required.

```
// connectivityCode.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-3awwl.mongodb.net/";
mongoose.connect(uri, {
  dbName: 'bing_bot'
}).catch((e)=>{
  console.log('Database connectivity error ',e)
})

module.exports = mongoose; // <-- exporting

// model.js
const mongoose = require('./connectivityCode.js') // <-- importing
// rest of the code
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me ! But same ia have tried using MongoClient (check updated question) and it work but why not Mongoose

Comment: if i use mlabs instead of mongoDB atlas it works fine